# stderr and stdout in separate files

Tags: php, exec

I am using [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966/987104) answer, but I want to get one file for stderr and one file for stdout.

This is what I currently have:

`exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));`

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: A stupid one. I tend to ask prematurely. I need another throwaway....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ask a proper question, since I don't really know what you mean. I'm going to assume you want to separate the output and error file?

If you want separate files for stdout and stderr, you need to remove the redirection `2>&1` (which redirects stderr to stdout).

```
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>%s & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $errorfile, $pidfile));
```